# Infinite Lists / Streams in ReScript

Tags: ocaml, reason, bucklescript, rescript

I can't seem to find the correct typing for an infinite list in ReScript.

I first tried:

```
type rec stream<'a> = ('a, () => ('a, stream<'a>))
```

Which was incorrect because ReScript thought the type was cyclic. So instead I tried:

```
type rec stream<'a> = ('a, Lazy.t<() => ('a, stream<'a>)>)
```

Which still gave me a type error.

Ultimately I am trying to get this piece of code to work but it fails due to the type signature being infinite.

```
let rec from: (int, Lazy.t<() => (int, Lazy.t<...>) = (x: int) => {
    (x, () => Lazy.from_fun(from(x+1)))
}
```

Comment: You can reuse OCaml's Seq, which is an infinite stream: https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Seq.html –it doesn't have any native dependencies, so you should just be able to copy and paste it directly into your project.

Comment: Yeah, I could do it with a variant and some way of ending the list, I was just trying to avoid that

Comment: There's a `-rectypes` flag you can pass the compiler which should have it accept this.

Comment: To provide more context as to why I was avoiding it as well. I want someone to **always** be able to get a `next`, even if the "end" occurs because `next` keeps returning `None`. Therefore, the type itself defines that there will always be a next rather than pretending / hoping there always is. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your only objection to `Sequence` is the `Nil` case, you can define

```
type rec stream<'a> = { x:'a, next:() => stream<'a> }
```

The difference with your definition is that we are creating a new recursive type, rather than trying to define a recursive type expression.

EDIT:

The difference between using a tuple or a record is that tuples are structurally typed whereas records are nominally typed.

This changes everything in term of equality and identity.

In particular the original definition can be read as

```
type stream0<'a> = ('a, () => 'b ) as 'b
```

Then whenever one wants to compare a type `stream0<'a>` with a tuple type, it might be needed to expand this abbreviation an unbounded number of time.

For instance, this function is well-typed.

```
let f: stream0<int> => (int, ()=>(int,() => _)) = (x) => x
```

or this one:

```
let app_once = ((x,next)) => next ()
```

One important consequence here is that it is possible to use a `stream0<'a>` in a context where a finite stream was expected.
In other words, there are many have many potential equality between a stream0<'a> and a finite version of stream0<'a>.

Contrarily, the record definition of `stream<'a>` create a new and distinct type constructor `stream`.  Consequently, a `stream<'a>` can only ever be equal to `stream<'a>`. In other words, a function designed for a `stream<'a>`

```
let app_once  = {x;next} => next(())
```

cannot work with the type

```
type one_stream<'a> = { x:'a, next:() => ('a, ()) }
```

In practice, the recursive type of `stream0<'a>` and its many type equalities is more bothersome than useful, and such recursive types are disabled by default.

Comment: What is the difference between using a record vs a tuple here?

Comment: See the edit, but in brief tuple are structural whereas records are nominal.